# How to pass a prop into A Private route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using protected routes in my reactjs application, and I would like to know how to pass props in a protected route or a more elegant way to solve my problem.

I am unable to pass props into the private route. Here is my code for App.js ...where I want to pass the **products prop** into the **Products component**

I am using the products as an API call make to Commerce.js

```js
function App() {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
    setProducts(data);
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    
  }, []);

  console.log(products);

  return (
    
    <Router>
      <AuthProvider>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Products} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
          </Switch>
        </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my code for **Private Route**

```js
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {

    const { currentUser } = useAuth();

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
            }}
        >

        </Route>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: why don't you try with context api you have already a authcontext provider you can create one more to pass the data anywhere which will solve your prop passing problem